# iOS : Slow searching in SQLite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have created a dictionary app with SQL data base , but the problem is when users search a word in `UISearchBar` the searching process is very slow ! why this happens ? here is my code :

```
- (void)updateSearchString:(NSString*)aSearchString
{
    [self.myTable reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    searchbar.showsCancelButton = YES;

    if([searchText length] > 0) {

        dbClass=[[DB alloc]init];
        [dbClass searchWord:searchText];

    }else
    {
        dbClass=[[DB alloc]init];
        [dbClass searchWord:@""];
    }

    [self.myTable reloadData];

}
```

Table view codes :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    appClass = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"%d",appClass.wordList.count);
    return  appClass.wordList.count;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    appClass = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    readerClass = (Reader *)[appClass.wordList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text  = readerClass.Name;


    return cell;
}
```

EDITED :

```
    -(void)searchWord:(NSString *)txt{

    NSMutableArray *DB_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    NSString *dbPath=[self getDBPath];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *sql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM DIC Where Name LIKE \'%@%%\' ",txt];

        //        NSLog(@"%@",sql);

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String] , -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSInteger oid = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);

                const char* f1 = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);
                NSString *oName = f1 == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:f1];

                const char* f2 = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2);
                NSString *oMean = f2 == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:f2];


                const char* f3 = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3);
                NSString *oPron = f3 == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:f3];

                NSInteger bm = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 5);

                readerClass = [[Reader alloc]initWithReadDB:oid Name:oName Mean:oMean Pron:oPron bookMark:bm];

                [DB_Array addObject:readerClass];

            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error retrieving data from database.");
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"Error: Can't open database!");
        NSLog(@" DB Name %@",viewController.dbName);
    }

    AppDelegate *appDelegateClass = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegateClass.wordList removeAllObjects];
    [appDelegateClass.wordList=DB_Array mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: what you do in searchWord method?

Comment: NSLog your SELECT statement to be sure you're getting what you expect.

Comment: And keep in mind that LIKE is quite slow.

Comment: @HotLicks so what should use it instead ?

Comment: Well, no better option, probably (if you need the wildcard support), but you just need to compensate somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the field you are searching on should be an index, otherwise you regress into a linear search over all records in the database.

Second, you should not use LIKE in that manner, as you are most likely going to regress into a linear search.  Instead, you should de-normalize your data so that you can more easily search for substrings.  You will end up with a larger database, but your search will be much faster.

Without much more detailed information about your specific search, it's hard to tell.

Finally, even if we had specific information, we could only do so much.

The only real way for you to determine where your performance bottleneck is, and whether changes actually fix it, you need to use performance tools (like Instruments) to gather data, and run lots of tests to determine exactly what is happening.

Really, forums like these can only do so much.  People can recognize horribly inefficient algorithms, but we are really terrible at spotting performance issues.  That's why we have analysis tools.  Learn to use them, and your life will be much simpler.

Good Luck!

**EDIT**

To address comments:  Using `LIKE` is not a string comparison.  It is, well, "like" a string comparison :-).  It accepts wildcards, and has to do more work for comparison.  It is pretty slow and can easily degrade into a linear search.

When talking about denormalizing, I mean take the `Name` field and break it out into a searchable field all its own.  Remove case and diacritic markings.  Maybe even break each name into N names, based on length.  Use the "searchable" field as a map to the real data items.  Databases are great for this.

Or, by doing some analysis, you can probably determine that after some number of characters (guess around 3-4), the number of prefix matches is small enough for an efficient search.  You can then make permutations on those.

Also, from the edited code, it looks like the database is being opened every time.  **That can be a killer.**  Other than that, I don't know much about using straight-sqlite API, so I can't comment on that part.

Comment: Questioner is using LIKE to find a string starting with the entered text. I agree an index would help, but can't see what you mean about denormalizing in this context.

Comment: Break the strings of this field out into a separate attribute of words and/or parts of words for more efficient searching.  Even breaking them out into a different data structure if necessary.  An index does not help if your search "skips" leading characters to find matches on internal characters/words because you still have to examine every entry to see if it matches.

Comment: Fine, but the search in this particular question /doesn't/ skip leading characters.

Comment: To expand on a point you made. I believe opening an SQLite database brings the entire database into memory. So, every time he does the alloc init for the database class it is unloading and then loading the SQLite database. A better way to do this would be to create a singleton instance of dbClass that way the database is only ever loaded once into the application.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing i wouldn't do is to allocate space every time the user change something in the search bar .... Init the database in the *viewDidLoad* method ...

But I think it's even better to save the necessary information for the UITableView in an NSDictionary or something and search over this Array/Dictionary ... 
I have done this in one of my Apps and it works very fine (the table has over 7000 rows)

Greez Chris

Comment: Your recommendation to store all the data in memory for searching is a trade-off between startup time and per-search time. Also you may have more data than will reasonably fit in memory. So it's not always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should do the searching on a background thread, to prevent locking the UI. That way it will feel much faster to the user.

Here is how to do this:
[Searching on a Background Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421181/searching-on-a-background-thread-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate `LIKE '%word%'` will not use the index, *`LIKE 'word%'`*, however, will.

I suggest making the index case-insensitive (`COLLATE NOCASE`), which would be expected from a dictionary lookup.